# Does chrome app id for extensions affect sync storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension for bookmarks. In the application, I make use of chrome.storage.sync. However, when I'm testing to install the application from a zip file I get different app id:s. This seems to affect sync and thus I'm wondering if there is a way to work around this.

Comment: I wonder why the title refers to `local storage` while the question is about `storage.sync`...

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the appropriate value for the `key` property in your manifest (and make sure you always use the same *.pem* file for packaging your extension).
Quoting **[the docs](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/key.html)** on manifest's `key` property:

> This value can be used to control the unique ID of an extension, app, or theme when it is loaded during development.
>
> To get a suitable key value, first install your extension from a *.crx* file (you may need to **[upload your extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard)** or **[package it manually](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging.html)**). Then, in your **[user data directory](http://www.chromium.org/user-experience/user-data-directory)**, look in the file *`Default/Extensions/<extensionId>/<versionString>/manifest.json`*. You will see the key value filled in there.

Comment: Hmm im doing testing of the application at the moment is this still necessary? is ther no otherway of setting the key.

Comment: @PabloKarlsson: Seems like I had missed one of the links. Have you taken a look at the `package it manually` option ? Does this work for you ?

Comment: @PabloKarlsson: Have you been to able to make this work ? If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider accepting it.