# How do I test the Sync feature of the chrome extension during development

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension which requires you to sign in to chrome before using it, post which you could save some values (*which I store it in the Sync storage*)  and the same is expected to get Synced whenever I Sign into chrome from some other machine using the same Sign in info.

I tested the extension and the info is being stored successfully on the machine where i am saving it. But the same info is not synced to the other machine. Just to make it clear,I have also installed the extension in the other machine's chrome as well.

I have used the following code in the background js for syncing purpose-

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, areaname) {
          if(areaname=="sync")
          {alert('Storage Changed' + changes);}}
```

so that I get an alert indicating that the event is getting fired.

I don't get this alert in the other machine; indicating the sync didnt happen.

I looked up  [Sync settings](https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync/),it shows that the sync just happened. But there was no alert.

Is it so, that we can test syncing during development of the extension ?

I have been through [Does-chrome-app-id-for-extensions-affect-sync-storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970833/does-chrome-app-id-for-extensions-affect-sync-storage)

Does the App Id has to do anything with it ??

**UPDATE** -  I found the answer. Let me elaborate how I did it. -

This page [developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/packaging) explains how to package and extension manually. Please go through that before proceeding.

***Step 1*** - I deleted the extension that I had installed in both the machines.( I had installed it using the Load unpacked extension option before)

***Step 2*** - I followed the link above and made a manual package file with .crx and .pem file

***Step 3*** - While I was signed in into the two machines using the same gmail account, I shared and installed this .crx file by drag-dropping the file into the browser. (It asks for confirmation and proceeds to install)

***Step 4*** - After following Step-3 on both the machines, I now have my extensions installed in both browsers.

***Step 5***- I saved values using my extension in one browser and voila, after a while, it appeared in the other machine.

***Step 6***- But One important thing though, the data was synced automatically without the alert that I wanted to display-

```
if(areaname=="sync") {alert('Storage Changed' + changes);}}
```

So I assume that this listener code was not important in my case anyways. Hope this helps other guys looking for the solution.

Comment: Your code has a typo, that you repeat in comments: `\`` before `alert`. Double-check that.

Comment: Could you convert your comments into an edit to the question? It's hard to read.

Comment: Moved my answer to an edit to the question